# How should Tcode be used in JCO program

Tags: sap-gui, sap-basis, jco

How do I set the Transaction Code (TCODE) in a JCO program and then fetch the required function?

e.g. if I need to access SE11 or SE13 related function?

Is the TCODE setting really important?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JCO programs call RFC-enabled module function. A Transaction code is *not* associated with such a function (se93 will show you the type of object that can be associated with any TCode).

se11 allows to display (and modify) the structure of a table/view/structure. How do you want a RFC call on a distant server to interact with that ?